# Unfortunately, Software Update has stopped OTA (LG G2 Rooted)

Tags: ota-update, lg-g2

Whenever I click it, I get the "Unfortunately, Software Update has stopped" message and the app closes. Picture is not of my phone, I found it from another post that was not answered.

[image: screenshot]

My phone was trying to update automatically but would fail during the process. I read a forum saying to restore some hotspot files that I had changed to get the free hotspot. I must have done something wrong in trying to find the stock hotspot files and now my phone wont even start to try and update.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Just open your setting>apps>software update>clear data. You are done...!!!